# Does setting 'iOS Distribution' for 'Code Signing Identity' mean that you cannot Run that configuration in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, code-signing

I really want to understand what the implications of setting the `iOS Distribution` code signing means. I have a `Release` and `Ad-hoc` (cloned from Release) configuration which both are designed to be distributed on TestFlight. This means they both need to have `iOS Distribution` code signing.  I set provisioning profile to automatic.

[image]

Whenever I try to run either of `Release` or `Ad-hoc` configurations on a development iPad device, I get the error

```
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles include the devices:
My iPad
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.4'
```

... due to the `iOS Distribution` setting choosing a Distribution provisioning profile.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get these configurations to run on a test device?

I want to do this to see the behaviour of the app as it would be like when distributed. i.e. with the preprocessor flag `DEBUG` switched off.

---

For comparison, when I create a fresh Xcode project and set `iOS Distribution` for its `Code Signing Identity` and then try to run on a device, Xcode offers `Fix Issue`, which when selected sorts everything out for me and  I'm able to run the app on a test device with ease.

I presume that Xcode must have downloaded or applied the wildcard development provisioning profile and applied that... despite me asking for it to be signed as `iOS Distribution`. Very confusing.

My only workaround at the minute is to manually set the identity `iOS Development` when I want to do testing. This is not ideal.

Comment: Code signing in Xcode is so broken. I wasted so many hours on this. I do not know the perfect answer to your question. What seems to help me is to open Keychain app and delete all the Xcode related certificates and keys. Then open the member centre web site and delete everything from there as well. Cleaning project, restarting Xcode and let it "Fix the issue".